# In Android Studio, set android:text from strings.xml, but back to text later

Tags: android, android-studio, text

I set android:text like below

```
android:text="@string/app_name"
```

But it will be changed to the following format later.

```
android:text="TestApp"
```

How to resolve it in Android Studio?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure... But if you put cursor on this property, it will be displayed as **@string/app_name**

Comment: When you will click on it, it will show you app_name, it just shows shadow to users inside xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of android studio. It looks up the value of the resource and previews it for you so you don't have to go to the resource file and look it up manually.

It is only a visual preview. It does not affect your code/xml in any way.

Comment: Plain and simple. You can even see that the text preview have a "light green" background color. Same happens for dimensions. This is the correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim and Mauker.